# Calculation of geometrical center from the set of XYZ coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of 3D coordinates for molecule composed of 31 atoms, stored in the nested array list:

```
[[121.133, 146.696, 139.126], [121.207, 145.489, 138.437], [122.058, 145.337, 137.335], [121.972, 143.689, 136.593], [123.209, 143.616, 135.31], [124.536, 143.881, 135.697], [124.87, 145.234, 135.928], [126.179, 145.569, 136.301], [127.156, 144.591, 136.455], [126.838, 143.258, 136.229], [123.824, 146.34, 135.736], [125.543, 142.913, 135.853], [123.008, 142.449, 134.454], [120.662, 143.598, 135.938], [122.362, 142.722, 137.625], [122.857, 146.427, 136.913], [122.764, 147.633, 137.625], [121.914, 147.77, 138.718], [123.101, 146.373, 134.374], [122.534, 147.208, 134.333], [122.482, 145.576, 134.33], [124.016, 146.346, 133.138], [125.066, 147.46, 133.272], [124.449, 148.847, 133.177], [123.972, 149.313, 131.947], [123.409, 150.582, 131.856], [123.322, 151.385, 132.993], [123.796, 150.925, 134.221], [124.36, 149.655, 134.314], [122.769, 152.634, 132.905], [123.339, 153.323, 133.255]]
```

so each sublist consists of XYZ coordinates for each atom and totally there are 31 sublists corresponed to each atom. I need to calculate geometrical center of this molecule using this set of coordinates as the input, thus producing 1 point with X Y Z.

Is it possible to do it using numpy.mean or other standard python libraties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. Just use

```
import numpy as np

def center(nested_array_list):
    a = np.array(nested_array_list)
    mean = np.mean(a, axis=0)
    return mean[0], mean[1], mean[2]  # x, y, z
```

Comment: just one question: how would it be possible to set up the number of flots after in the resulted numpy array ? presently it gives me something like (124.24238709677419, 146.01383870967749, 134.21829032258063), while I need to keep only 3 digits after . ?

Comment: For `printing`, you can use [np.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) -> `np.set_printoptions(precision=3)`, otherwise you can call `np.around(mean, decimals=3)`.

Comment: So I defined meann = numpy.around(mean, decimals=3) and then returned meann[0], meann[1], meann[2]. Eventually it prints OK for y and z but x still has a lot of numbers: (123.50700000000001, 146.672, 135.303)

Comment: That's because of the [floating point number representation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). What you see is the closest possible number to `123.507` that can be represented by bits in python's floating point format. To make sure exactly three characters are printed after the decimal point, you can `print("xyz = [%.3f, %.3f, %.3f]" % tuple(mean))`.

Comment: sorry for the question, and this print statement should be inside or outside the function ? is it possible to store this in the variable? since in the script I use these values to ocnvert them from list to string format

Answer (score 0):

*other standard python libraties*

You might do that using built-in `statistics` module. Consider following toy example:

```
import statistics
points = [[10,20,30],[90,40,60]]
center = [statistics.mean(i) for i in zip(*points)]
print(center)  # [50, 30, 45]
```

I used `zip` combined with unpacking (`*`) to transpose points, which result in list with three tuples, which are holding points X-cordinates, points Y-cordinates, points Z-cordinates. Then I used `statistics.mean` function on each tuple via so-called list-comprehension.